# Represent a Random Binary Tree as Array?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I'm reading about [Eytzinger's method](http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1d/ods-java/node52.html) for storing binary trees as an array.

[image]

I like how straight forward this is, but in my specific case I need to store a random binary tree, that isn't consistent in structure. Something like this where the amount of nodes at any given depth is not predictable:

[image]

Is there a simple method for implementing something like this with arrays?

*Note: No preference on language in answers.*

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why the naive approach of just having 'empty' cells in the array (where the tree's depth is smaller) is not enough? Are you looking to save any amount of space, even at the price of the solution's complexity?

Comment: @OriBar-ilan that would make sense. I never considered it as a possibility. In retrospect it seems obvious.

Comment: Then I'll add that as an official answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution can be simply to create an array as if the tree was a *full binary tree*, and just fill the missing nodes with "empty" cells.

Empty can be indicated with special values (depending on the domain) for example: null, negative integer etc.

If no special values are available, you can create another same-sized Boolean array that will hold the answer to "is cell empty?".

By the way, such a tree, where each node has at most 2 children, is simply called a *Binary Tree* (no need for the word *random*).
The tree that you call a Binary Tree, where every node has either no children or exactly 2 children, is called a *Complete Binary Tree*.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the operations you need to perform on the tree following option might or might not work for you.

[image]

You can represent this tree with array where empty subtrees are not stored. Only leafs need to have empty children stored. So the tree would be represented as follows (empty node is denoted with `-1`).

`3 3 1 2 2 -1 -1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1`

Let's denote the array as `A[i]` where `i >= 0`, then:

`A[0]` - root

`A[1]` - left child of the root

`A[2]` - right child of the root

`A[3]` - left child of `A[1]`

`A[4]` - right child of `A[1]`

`A[5]` - left child of `A[2]` (since there is no child and it's a leaf - it's empty)

`A[6]` - right child of `A[2]` (since there is no child and it's a leaf - it's empty)

`A[7]` - left child of `A[3]`

`A[8]` - right child of `A[3]`

etc.

I find this structure especially useful for storing the tree, other operations might be tricky to implement.

Answer (score 0):

So far I'm finding that it will be easier and more efficient to implement such a tree with objects.

Each node can be based on a class which stores `parent, left, and right`.

***Example of node class in Ruby:***

```
class Node
  def initialize(parent)      
    # Instance variables  
    @parent = parent
    @left = nil
    @right = nil
  end
end
```

***Function to generate a random tree in Ruby:***

```
def makeTree(root, count)
  random = Node.new(root)
  treeFull = TRUE
  if root.instance_variable_get(:@left) == nil and root.instance_variable_get(:@right) == nil
    rand(0..1) == 1 ? root.instance_variable_set(:@left, random) : root.instance_variable_set(:@right, random)
    treeFull = FALSE
  elsif root.instance_variable_get(:@left) == nil
    root.instance_variable_set(:@left, random)
  else
    root.instance_variable_set(:@right, random)
  end
  if count>0
    if treeFull == FALSE
      if rand(0..1) == 1
        makeTree(root, count-1)
      elsif rand(0..1) == 1
        makeTree(root.instance_variable_get(:@left), count-1)
      else
        makeTree(root.instance_variable_get(:@right), count-1)
      end
    end
    makeTree(random, count-1)
  end
end
```

*Apologies for quickly answering my own question. I find the process of detailing my problem here useful. Also looking for feedback and other methods.*